# Merge Sort With String Vectors C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, mergesort

Hello all I am a noob to recursion and I'm feeling like banging my head against the wall. I watched some videos, read the chapter and have been trying to figure out the answer to this problem for over 6 hours now with no luck. My professor gave us the following code and we have to mod it from there. Note: We are reading 52k words from a file and then sorting them using this algorithm. Not sure if that matters but thought I would add the info just in case.
include

```
using namespace std;

vector<int> MergeUsingArrayIndices(const vector<int> & LHS,
                               const vector<int> & RHS)
{
vector<int> ToReturn;

int i = 0;  // LHS index
int j = 0;  // RHS index

while ((i < LHS.size()) && (j < RHS.size()))
{
    if (LHS[i] < RHS[j])
    {
        ToReturn.push_back(LHS[i]);
        ++i;
    }
    else
    {
        ToReturn.push_back(RHS[j]);
        ++j;
    }
}

while (i < LHS.size())
{
    ToReturn.push_back(LHS[i]);
    ++i;
}

while (j < RHS.size())
{
    ToReturn.push_back(RHS[j]);
    ++j;
}

return ToReturn;
}
```

Except now we have to make this work from just a single vector. This is what I have so far.

```
vector<string> MergeUsingArrayIndices(vector<string> & LHS,
int START, int MID, int MIDPLUSONE, int END)
{

    vector<string> ToReturn;
    int i = 0;  // LHS index
    int j = MIDPLUSONE;  // RHS index

    while ((i <= MID) && (j <= END))
    {
        if (LHS[i] < LHS[j])
        {
            ToReturn.push_back(LHS[i]);
            ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            ToReturn.push_back(LHS[j]);
            ++j;
        }
    }

    while (i <= MID)
    {
        ToReturn.push_back(LHS[i]);
        ++i;
    }

    while (j <= END)
    {
        ToReturn.push_back(LHS[j]);
        ++j;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < ToReturn.size(); ++k)
    {
        LHS[k] = ToReturn[k];
    }
    return ToReturn;

}
```

Plus this is the call prior to the function.

```
void MergeSort(vector<string> & VECTOR, int START, int END)
{

if (END > START)
{
    int MID = (START + END) / 2;
    MergeSort(VECTOR, START, MID);
    MergeSort(VECTOR, MID + 1, END);
    MergeUsingArrayIndices(VECTOR, START, MID, (MID+1), END);
}
}

void Merge(std::vector<string> & VECTOR)
{

MergeSort(VECTOR, 0, VECTOR.size()-1);
}
```

[Console Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBnsZ.png)

Basically it is sorting but not very well since not everything is in alphabetical order. That was just a small sample of words from the list.

Thank you and best regards,

DON'T GET MARRIED.

UPDATE FOR: PNKFELIX
It tried the following;

```
        vector<string> ToReturn;
        int i = START;       // LHS index
        int j = MIDPLUSONE;  // RHS index

    while (i <= MID && j <= END)
    {
        if (LHS[i] <= LHS[j])
        {
            ToReturn[START] = LHS[i];
            //ToReturn.push_back(LHS[i]);
            ++START;
            ++i;
        }
```

and so on but this made the code worse so I am sure that is not what you were referring to. I have been up for days trying to figure this out and I cannot sleep......

The one thing you pointed to that is bothering me because I see why it's not happening but cannot fix is the call

I'm guessing that is why you used the apple, pear, orange, banana example. (very clever by the way). You can lead a horse to water but cannot make it drink. However, I still do not see how to fix this? I tried replacing my i = 0; with i = START as I now see this is probably the culprit when comparing the right side since it should start at that position but it actually made my code worse? What else am I missing here?

I have so much going on and cannot stand it when professors do stuff like this (my community college isn't great for CIS and my professor has never taught this class before). I cannot rest until I figure it out but the textbook is so far above my head (the professor even apologized for the textbook at the beginning of the semester saying it was too advanced for us but it is what they gave him) and uses a totally different approach (two separate arrays instead of one vector). What am I supposed to do with START? I have spent so much time on this and am dying to know the answer. Maybe that makes me lazy but there is a point where you can only think about something so much. I love to learn but this is not learning as I've hit my limit. I am missing something and don't know how to begin desk checking what it is. I am assuming the right hand side of each vector comparison is not sorted but how do I fix that? Is it because start is not always zero (example: for the right hand side )? I am not good at sorting algorithms (because I am not very bright (although I study allot)) as it is, and this is a new twist. It's like handing someone a bubble sort that is broken and asking them to desk check it, fix whats wrong with it, and make it more efficient yet they've never seen one working before.

Comment: When trying to debug code like this, a good second step (since the first was recognizing that the output is wrong) is to try to *reduce* the input to something as small as possible that still exposes the bug.

Comment: (For example, can you come up with a list of say four words that when fed to your algorithm, still comes out improperly sorted?) Then, once you have that smaller input, you'll be in a better position to work through the concrete details of what your program is doing to that input.

Comment: Also, do you have compiler warnings turned on? For example, that `START` parameter in your `MergeUsingArrayIndices` is completely unused; that might be a hint to a problem in your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nice thing about a problem like this is that there's nothing specific to C++ here. One can take the proposed code and port it to pretty much any other reasonable language (e.g. JavaScript) and then debug it there to determine what is going wrong.

A good practice in any program is to document the assumptions and invariants of the code. If these invariants are simple enough, you can even check that they hold within the code itself, via `assert` statements.

So, lets see: from looking at how `MergeUsingArrayIndices` is invoked by `MergeSort`, it seems like your approach is a recursive divide-and-conquer: You first divide the input in two at a midpoint element, sort each side of the divided input, and then merge the two parts.

From that high-level description, we can identify a couple of invariants that must hold on entry to `MergeUsingArrayIndices`: the left half of LHS must be sorted, and the right half of LHS must also be sorted. We can check that these two conditions hold as we merge the vector, which may help us identify the spot where things are going wrong.

I took the original code and ported it as faithfully as I could to Rust (my preferred programming language), then added some assertions, and some print statements so that we can see where the assertions fail.

- (There was one other change I forgot to mention above: I also got rid of the unused return value from `MergeUsingArrayIndices`. The array you're building up is solely used as temporary storage that is later copied into `LHS`; you never use the return value and therefore we can just remove that from the function's type entirely.)

Here is that code in a running playpen:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bd61b9572ea45b7139bf081cb51dc491&version=stable&backtrace=0

Some leading questions:

- What indices is the assertion comparing when it reports that `LHS[i]` is in fact not less than `LHS[i+1]`?
- The printouts report when the vector should be sorted at certain subranges: 0...0, 1...1, 0...1, et cetera. The indices you found above (assuming they are the same as the ones I found) are not within one of these subranges; so we in fact do not have a justification for trying to claim that `LHS[i]` is less than `LHS[i+1]`! So what happened, why does the code think that they should fall into a sorted subrange of the vector?
- Strong hint number one: I left on a warning that the compiler issues about the code.
- Strong hint number two: Try doing the exercise I left in the comment above the `MergeUsingArrayIndices` function.

Comment: Pnkfelix, I feel bad because you put so much work into this and I'm unfortunately going to have to give up on this one for now. I'm just not grasping what is going on and recursive logic is brand new to me. I had a hard enough time understanding how a factorial could be written recursively much less for a sorting algorithm. I looked at your code and it seems that I may not be comparing all the elements but am not sure how. Also I know I am not using the START parameter but I think it's unneeded because I don't have to watch and count it since i'm using push.back for the vector? Sorry&thankyou

Comment: I agree that if you have trouble understanding recursive factorial, then you should work first on that before jumping into this. Having said that, I will attempt a concrete illustration: Rather than focus on code, get a deck of cards. Mix up the deck. Then try to understand recursive sorting by first dividing the deck in two; manually sort the left half (by any means), and the right half. Then merge the two by hand. If you can do that, then you should at least be a good ways towards understanding merge sort. (And then you might be able to work through the example here more effectively.)

Comment: Oh, and I think you do need the `START` parameter. You just haven't seen why yet. :)

Comment: I will give you a big hint, since  your solution is so close to something that should work: A *huge* part of any recursive algorithm is that it only guarantees correct outputs if it is given correct inputs. In the case of merge-sort, it will only produce sorted output if the two input lists are completely sorted. As soon as you feed in any unsorted input, then all bets are off as to whether the output will be sorted properly. In your case, you are traversing parts of the list that are not sorted (the bullet points in my answer were pointing this out); how can that possibly be the case?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I understand better how a merge sort works, i guess I would never be able to write the code for it myself (or am a long ways away from doing so) if I had come up with the idea for it myself. However, I don't understand how they would not be presorted? Doesn't the recursive algorithm make sure that the first time a call to the function MergeUsingArrayIndices that only two elements are being compared, and then so on? (So technically they're supposed to be sorted already?) Do I have to sort the two halfs first? doesn't that defeat the purpose?.

Comment: See above I added new info to my question towards the bottom. I cannot figure out how or why the right hand side is not sorted.

Comment: PNKFElLIX thank you! I figured it out (Actually my professor did). My int i should have been equal to start every time and when copying from LHS into ToReturn I should have used LHS[START+K] = ToReturn[K]; The good news is that recursive functions apparently aren't used often so I won't encounter this too often. I also had a hard time with sorting algorithms a few classes ago but that was much easier to learn. I think this was a test to my limit of learning for now. I'll keep working at it but this was and still is over my head since I cannot even desk check the merge sort function properly.

Comment: congrats, I'm glad you persevered and got your code working. In my opinion Recursion is especially hard to understand in a language like C++ where you are mutating arrays all over the place. Maybe someday in the future when you have time, take a look at the textbook here, which uses a friendlier language: http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/

Comment: and actually the follow-on edition of HtDP is more fun to work through, since it jumps into playing with images and animations and making simple video games right off the bat: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/

Comment: Thank you pnkfelix! Your awesome and I find it really cool that you took that much time out of your day to help!

Answer (score 0):

Use strcmp(LHS[i],LHS[j])<0 in if condition

Comment: I don't know what that means?